# React native re-render not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hope you guys are doing well during this tough time.

so I'm a react native newbie and I'm trying to build my first game which is slip click game and the main idea behind it is I have a 30 buttons each second only one of those button is active and the user must click that particular one and if he clicked the wrong one his failed attempts increases by one other.

so what I did is the following:

```
export default function App() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(30);
const [random, setRandom] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * count));
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
let arr = [];

for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
  arr[index] = index;
}

setData(arr);

return () => {
  //cleanup
};
}, [count]);

useEffect(() => {
const inter = setInterval(() => {
  setRandom(Math.floor(Math.random() * count));
}, 1000);

return () => {
  clearInterval(inter);
};
}, []);

const handlePress = (index) => {
alert("you pressed heart no #" + index);
};

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>{random}</Text>
  <View style={styles.gameBody}>
    {data.map((i) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => handlePress(i)}
        key={i}
        style={{ ...styles.gameItem, opacity: random === i ? 1 : 0.3 }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.gameTxt}>❤️</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
  </View>
</View>
);
}
```

what I expected this code to do is each second the random number changes and accordingly the random button change it's opacity to give the user the feeling that it's the current active one but this is not happening, so how can I Fix this one??

thank you in advance and don't forget to stay home.

Answer (score 0):

**It was working from the beginning and I changed this like**

```
<Text style={styles.gameTxt}>❤️</Text>
```

*to*

```
<Text style={styles.gameTxt}>{random === i ? '❤️' : ''}</Text>
```

**and it worked**